# fatal error on calling function from another class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having trouble on calling the function from a different class. I have this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func addToOrder(orderNumber:String) {

        orderCount.text = orderNumber

    }

}
```

Now in my other class:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

   func addToOrder(button: UIButton) {


      ViewController().addToOrder("100")

      //I also tried

       var menu = ViewController()
       menu.addToOrder("100")

     }

}
```

I'm getting error on this line

```
    orderCount.text = orderNumber
```

with this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: `MenuController()` is a constructor call, so `MenuController().addToOrder("100")` creates a new MenuController() every time, is that what you want?

Comment: You are instantiating a new instance of `MenuController` so presumably none of its properties will be initialised

Comment: I've updated my question, I forgot to change the original class name which is MenuController to ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for that.

Follow this step:

first of all add this in your first viewController where you want to update text:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshTable:", name: "refresh", object: nil)

}
```

Which will add an observer when your load your first view and also add this helper method which will call when you come back to this view:

```
func refreshTable(notification: NSNotification) {
    let orderDetail = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("order")  //this will read your integer which you will save on second view.
    orderCount.text = "\(orderDetail)"

}
```

In your next view add this code when you are coming back to previous view.

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
    //store your int here
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(100, forKey: "order")
    //send notification to first view.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's `orderCount` (which probably is a UILabel) which is `nil` at initialization-time. If this is a IBOutlet created in a storyboard, you will need to store your text as a separate property, and set the text of your Label to this property in your ´viewDidLoad´ method

Comment: Yes but at this point `ViewController().addToOrder("100")` ,  `orderCount` is still `nil` because your view has not been loaded yet. If you add some `NSLog` statments in both places you will see what I mean.

Comment: I did `ViewController().orderCount.text = "0"` and `ViewController().addToOrder("100")` in the action I'm calling it. but still the same